# How many variables we can declare in data class primary constructor at a time in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say we have 100 variables for creating a data class, so we need to declare all 100 variables in primary constructor or is there any other way?

Comment: I am not sure but 100 variables on constructor seams like a big number to me. By the way, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say we have 100 variables for creating a data class

Let's say that is a bad idea from a maintainability standpoint. I would be nervous about a code-generated class having 100 properties, let alone one that is hand-maintained.

> so we need to declare all 100 variables in primary constructor

A `data class` can have regular properties, like any other Kotlin class. So all 100 do not have to be in the primary constructor.

However, only those properties in the primary constructor are taken into account in the "special stuff" that we get generated for us with a `data class`, such as:

- `toString()`
- `copy()`
- equality operations

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare all variables somewhere. As far as I know, it can be combination of primary constructor, properties and `init` block. Something like this:

```
data class Example(val first : String, val second : String) {
    val bothNotEmpty : Boolean = first.isNotEmpty() && second.isNotEmpty()
    val randomUUID : String

    init {
        randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
}
```